# How to properly use ignore_user_abort()

Tags: php, forms, csv, file-upload, large-files

I have a script that reads large csv files from the server. As you can see before I initialize the upload I use `ignore_user_abort(true)` . Should I be worried about closing this after the upload has finished ? Am I using this properly ? Is there a better way to go about this issue ?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

try {
    $filePath = $_POST['filepath'];
    $electionType = $_POST['electionType'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $updateMethod = $_POST['updateMethod'];
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    $upload = new UploadController($filePath,$year,$electionType,$updateMethod );
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'The fields arent setup properly <br>';
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

Firstly, I have no idea what UploadController is or what it does. Nor do I know what you are trying to *achieve* through the use of `ignore_user_abort()`. Further, the slowest thing I would *expect* is the upload process itself, which will have finished by the time your `ignore_user_abort()` executes.

> Should I be worried about closing this after the upload has finished

That really defeats the purpose of using ignore_user_abort() in the first place. If you want to take some action in the case where the connection is lost before the script terminates normally, then you should be polling `connection_aborted()`.